# Python converting list of strings to list of integers

Tags: python

hi I'm trying to convert this list of strings:
`lists=['111,222','121,121']`
into a list of integers but keep running into errors, any advice would be helpful.
I've tried:

```
results=[int(i) for i in lists]
print(results)
```

but keep getting "invalid literal for int() with base 10: '111,222'"

Comment: Please add expected, output and what have you tried... Also this is a pretty common question, are you sure there isn't some other post that answers it?

Comment: What integer do you expect the string `"111,222"` to be converted into?

Comment: 111222, but I want it as an int() instead of a str()

Comment: Well, Python doesn't support a thousands separator when converting strings to integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the commas, for example:

```
lists=['111,222','121,121']
result = [int(s.replace(',', '')) for s in lists]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[111222, 121121]
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
import re

lists=['111,222','121,121']
results = [ int("".join(re.findall('[0-9]+', element))) for element in lists ] 

# results = [111222, 121121]
```